# list of common first element in tuple of list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm new in python and I want to create a boolean search (information retrieval). This basically entails taking two lists of 2-tuples and creating a new list of 3-tuples by:

1) Taking the intersection of the lists restricted to the first entry of the tuples, and

2) Adding the second entry of the tuple in the intersection from both lists to the new 3-tuple. For example, if there is an element in each list with the first entry `a`, say `(a,b)` and `(a,c)`, then these should be merged to form `(a,b,c)` in the new list.

Here is a better example. I have two lists of tuple like this:

```
search_for_term1 =[(documentID1, term1_frequency),(documentID2, term1_frequency) ] 

search_for_term2 =[(documentID1, term2_frequency),(documentID3, term2_frequency) ]
```

Ex:

```
list1 = [(2, 9), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (7, 1), (6, 1), (8, 2)]

list2 = [(10, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1), (6, 5)]
```

Expected output:

```
[(documentID2, term1_frequency, term2_frequency), (documentID4, term1_frequency, term2_frequency), ... ]

out : [(2, 9, 1), (4, 2, 1), (6, 1, 5)]
```

Comment: Please...Explain the logic behind your output??

Comment: i want to return list with same docsID [(doc ID "first element of tuple in list" ,  term1 frequency " second element  of tuple in list1" ,  term2 frequency "second element of tuples in list 2) ...   ]

Comment: It's like an SQL join along the first entry of the tuples.

Comment: @DavidKleiman While reviewing your edit, I came close to rejecting it. I  appreciate the effort you put into turning this question into something understandable but such drastic edits run the risk of being rejected due to the possibility that they *may* conflict with the OP's intent. After careful consideration, I eventually decided that you were probably correct in your interpretation but for future reference, I thought I'd let you know that similar drastic edits run the risk of being rejected. I've had that happen with my edits when I was starting. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a simple implementation you can order the lists and then iterate over them together getting those elements that have the same `id`, to try to keep your complexity close to the O(N) you should keep the lists always sorted.

For example

```
list1.sort()
list2.sort()

results = []
try:
    iter1 = iter(list1)
    iter2 = iter(list2)
    i = iter1.next()
    j = iter2.next()
    while True:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            results.append((i[0], i[1], j[1]))
            i = iter1.next()
            j = iter2.next()
        elif i[0] < j[0]:
            i = iter1.next()
        else:
            j = iter2.next()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the several lists. Here's a generic solution.

```
def zipMerge(*lists):
    dicts = map(dict, lists)
    base = { }
    items = 0
    for d in dicts:
        items += 1
        for k,v in d.iteritems():
            if k not in base:
                base[k] = [k] + [None] * len(lists)
            base[k][items] = v

    return map(tuple, sorted(base.itervalues()))
```

To test...

```
list1 = [(2, 9), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (7, 1), (6, 1), (8, 2)]
list2 = [(10, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1), (6, 5)]
zipMerge(list1, list2)
```

Returns

```
[(2, 9, 1), (3, 1, None), (4, 2, 1), (5, 1, None), (6, 1, 5), (7, 1, None), (8, 2, None), (10, None, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with simple list comprehension as follows:

```
>>> list1 = [(2, 9), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (7, 1), (6, 1), (8, 2)]
>>> list2 = [(10, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1), (6, 5)]
>>> [(x,y,z) for (x,y) in list1 for (xx,z) in list2 if x == xx]
[(2, 9, 1), (4, 2, 1), (6, 1, 5)]
```